# Fail to install objccheckstyle using pip in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, pip, lxml

I'm trying to install [objccheckstyle](https://github.com/Azoft/objccheckstyle) with this command:

```
sudo pip install objccheckstyle
```

But it fails after it says

```
Running setup.py install for lxml
```

and I get this error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-DsaKIL/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-CFc6EG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-DsaKIL/lxml
```

I also tried `sudo pip install lxml`, but it looks like it fails when tries to import `libxml`:

```
#include "libxml/xmlversion.h"
```

I don't find `libxml` with `pip install`. What could I be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest Xcode's command line tools solved the problem.